# Show me the isometry, please.

Tags: analysis

The points, h, on a circle centered at (0, 1/2), of radius 1/2, except for the point at (0,1) are the set E.  They are projected from (0,1) onto the real line, $R$, in the $R^2$ plane, the x-axis, as the points (s,0) and may thus be identified by the function h(s) as the line of projection intersects the set E, a subset of the circle.  The set $R$ is given the metric $\rho=|{h(s)-h(t)}|$, where (s,0) and (t,0)  are points of R. The set E is dense in the circle, as the circle less one point.  I am struggling to show that the metric set $(R,\rho)$ is in isometry with the dense set, E.  I take E to be the metric set $(E,d(s,t))$, where $d(s,t)=|s-t|$ I presume. For $h(s)$ I take the x,y coordinates of the point of $E$, expressed in terms of $s$ on $R$.  This seems to lead me nowhere. I cannot demonstrate an isometry, maybe because I don't really know what $d$ is.

Comment: As you say, knowing the meaning of $d(s, t)$ is crucial to making progress. Where did the question come from...?

Comment: Intro to Topology, 2nd Edition, ONE, Sect 6, ex 3, p.27 w hint on p. 201.   Thanks for asking!

Comment: By Gamelin & Greene.  d = |s-t| does not work, as far as I can see.  The question is mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An isometry between two metric spaces (ms) is demonstrated by showing equality of the two metrics over the relevant domain. In the present case, the mses are (R,$\rho$) and (E,d).  The 1st metric $\rho$ = |(h(s),h(t))|, where the arguments are reals, s and t, and d = |h_1 - h_2|, where the arguments are points of E.  From the geometry of the projection from (1,0) onto the real line at (s,0):  h(s) in $\rho$ is the pair (x,y), where x= s/($s^2$ +1) and y = $s^2$/($s^2$+1). Using the same pair for the points h1 and h2 defining the metric d, the equality is established, and the isometry of the mapping of R onto E is shown.  The point of all this by G&G is to use isometry to "identify" the entire circle to the completion of R.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do any calculation, simply use the definition of $\rho$.
The isometry is just the map $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow E$ itself:
$$ \rho(s,t) = d(h(s),h(t)) $$
by *definition* of $\rho$, and where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  For an isometry, I need two metric sets, as I understand. I need to show that the metric $\rho$ applied to a pair of points in one set yields the same non-negative real number as does the other metric $d$ applied to the same pair. How do I do that in the present case, please?

Comment: Is an isometry a mapping, or is it the case where two metric functions yield the same result?    I thought it was the latter, and that it requires a calculation to show that both functions produce the same answer for a given pair of points.  Every metric is a mapping from a binary set to the non-negative reals, or so I thought.

Comment: Why a warning to be nice?  Have I been rude?   I don't think so.

Comment: Alehandro:  Are you implying that the $\rho$ metric is not really on E but on R;  that though the dependence on x, y through h is shown in the definition of $\rho$,  s and t are the independent variables and therefore $\rho$ is really identical to d(s,t) ?    If so, I find this presentation by G & G very unhelpful to the understanding of isometry.

Comment: An isometry between metric spaces $ (X_1,d_1) $ and $ (X_2,d_2) $ is a bijection $ f:X\rightarrow Y $ such that for all $x,y $ in $X_1$, you have that $ d_1(x,y) = d_2(f(x),f(y)) $. If I understand the problem correctly, you have the Euclidean metric $d$ on $E$ and the bijection $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow E$ is used to define $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}$ in exactly the way such that $h$ is then an isometry.

Comment: But |s-t| does not equal $\rho(h(s),h(t))$.   Where is the isometry?

Comment: h(s) = (s/ss+1, ss/ss+1)

Comment: h(s) is defined by the intersection of  the projecting line from (1,0) to (s,0) with the circle E.   This intersection has the coordinates given above, in terms of s on R.   The metrics are not equal.   Where is the isometry?